# Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.zza

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am making an app, in which i have to detect GAID and also show admob ad.
When i am trying to run the app, its giving me this error

> Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.zza

Here are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
}
```

I am trying to check if play-services are available, but i am getting the error.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Improved styling, [for further posts this help might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just worked when i updated services-auth-9.0.0 to services-auth-16.0.1 version.